# Show that lim(c_n) = A * B

Tags: general-topology

I'm working on a homework problem and almost finished with the proof but stuck with how to end it.

> Let the sequence $c_{n}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ be given by $c_{n} = a_{n} \cdot b_{n}$ where $\lim (a_{n}) = A$ and $\lim (b_{n}) = B$. Then $\lim (c_{n}) = A \cdot B$.

Here is my current attempt:

- Let $\epsilon > 0$
- Since $\lim (a_{n}) = A, \exists M_{1} \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t.
  \begin{equation*}
      \lvert a_{n} - A \rvert < \ldots \ \ \forall n \geq M_{1}
  \end{equation*}
- Since $\lim (b_{n}) = B, \exists M_{2} \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t.
  \begin{equation*}
      \lvert b_{n} - B \rvert < \ldots \ \ \forall n \geq M_{2}
  \end{equation*}
- Let $M = \max \{M_{1}, M_{2}\}$
- Then $\lvert a_{n} - A \rvert < \ldots$ and $\lvert b_{n} - B \rvert < \ldots$ for all $n \geq M$
- So,
  \begin{align*}
  \lvert c_{n} - (A \cdot B) \rvert &= \lvert (a_{n} \cdot b_{n}) - (A \cdot B) \rvert \\
      &= \ldots \\
  \end{align*}

I don't know what to set $\epsilon$ to be in this case and how to finish the proof. Any resource or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You don't set epsilon, it has to be true for all  $\epsilon > 0$. **Hint:** In the last equation add and subtract $a_n \cdot  B$ within the absolute value.

Comment: @GáborPálovics Thanks I'll give it a try soon once I get back home, but is the idea to add a form of 0 and be able to factor?

Comment: Yes. By definition the limit is linear, so you can use that property and give an upperbound which would only be true for all $\epsilon>0$ if the limit of $c_n - AB$ is $0$.

Comment: It's really strange you have it as a homework problem. Usually such properties of a limit are proved in class. Anyway, try writing $|a_nb_n-AB|=|a_nb_n-a_nB+a_nB-AB|$ and use the triangle inequality. Also, you will have to use the fact that a convergent sequence is bounded.

Comment: @Mark I've gotten to the point where I obtain $\lvert a_{n} \rvert \lvert b_{n} - B \rvert + \lvert B \rvert \lvert a_{n} - B \rvert$, from here $\lvert b_{n} - B \rvert$ should be less than some form of $\epsilon > 0$ as well as with the $\lvert a_{n} - A \rvert$, doing so with just $\epsilon$ I obtain $\epsilon \lvert a_{n} + B \rvert$

Comment: @Caayo As I said, a convergent sequence is bounded. So there is some constant $M$ such that $|a_n|\leq M$ for all $n$. Also, we may take $M$ large enough such that $M>|B|$. For large enough $n$ we have both $|a_n-A|<\frac{\epsilon}{2M}$ and $|b_n-B|<\frac{\epsilon}{2M}$. Then $|a_n||b_n-B|+|B||a_n-B|<M\frac{\epsilon}{2M}+M\frac{\epsilon}{2M}=\epsilon$.

Comment: @Mark Ah I got it, I was messing up with the portion where a convergent sequence is bounded. Much appreciated for the help!